# System Settings vs Settings?

Tags: settings, 15.04, system-settings

So I've upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 15.04 (which I regret, but it'll be an interesting learning experience and I'll see how I get along with other problems I've encountered so far as I've already solved some), but for some reason whenever I open the dash and type in "settings" to get to settings, there are two different settings icons that both lead to the same settings.

One is supposedly supposed to be specifically for GNOME (so it says) and the other one does not have a preview description. But both of them lead to regular system settings. It's not that big of a deal, I just want to know why this happened and how I can fix it.

There's some other fishy stuff too, such as a duplicate of "Online Accounts" showing up in the software center (yes they are the same system online account settings).

To add to that, Ubuntu also installed Ubuntu Touch on my computer, which gave me an additional set of settings that were meant for a mobile phone somehow. I've successfully removed these settings, but I found this extremely strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that actual binaries are stored in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. What you see appearing in dash is `.desktop` files which are sort of like shortcuts to programs. In those files there is a liine `Name` which is how it appears in dash and other search tools, like `gnome-do`

Now here's the problem: The .desktop files for `unity-control-center` and `gnome-control-center` have line `Name` exactly the same, as `System Settings`

Now, do this `grep -s 'Name' /usr/share/applications/* | awk '/-control-center/'`
You should see

```
/usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop:Name=System Settings
/usr/share/applications/unity-control-center.desktop:Name=System Settings
```

Speaking of 15.04 , this has nothing to do with this Ubuntu version. I've had it in 13.04 and 14.04. It's just a small quirk that can be easily corrected by editing one of the .desktop files

Comment: I navigated to that location and simply deleted the one that was named "settings" since the name between the two was actually different. Thanks!